# Filter CSV Carriage Return

Tags: powershell, csv, filtering

Trying to figure out how to filter items in specific CSV.

**CSV contents:**

```
ComputerName,Results
computerA      ," KB00000 is not installed 
c:\SomeTestFile Version is 2
c:\SomeTestFile Version is 11.0"
ComputerB   ,%windir%\somefile.exe is Version 1.2
```

I need it to filter based on the carriage return first in the second column and subsequently filter different parameters like "is version10" or "KB00000 is missing" out.

**Intended output in CSV:**

```
ComputerName,Results
computerA ,c:\SomeTestFile Version is 2
computerA ,c:\SomeTestFile Version is 11.0
ComputerB ,%windir%\somefile.exe is Version 1.2
```

Having a coding block. I can get the file imported but stuck on filtering.

```
$CSV = Import-Csv File.csv
```

Comment: Is your sample content the actual raw content of the CSV (when opened in a text editor)?

Comment: I typed it here but if you were to put it in csv it would look like:

ComputerName,Results
computerA      ," KB00000 is not installed 
c:\SomeTestFile Version is 2
c:\SomeTestFile Version is 11.0"
ComputerB   ,%windir%\somefile.exe is Version 1.2

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy/paste the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your given csv

This script:

```
## Q:\Test\2017\08\24\SO_45870618.ps1
$FileIn  = '.\FileIn.Csv'
$FileOut = '.\FileOut.Csv'

$Csv = Import-Csv $FileIn
$Csv

$CsvNew = ForEach ($Row in $Csv) {
    If (!($Row.ComputerName)){
        If ($Last) {$Row.ComputerName = $Last}
    }
    $Last = $Row.ComputerName
    ForEach ($line in ($Row.Results -Split('\r?\n')) ){
        If ($line -NotMatch '^\s*KB\d+\s+is'){
            [PSCustomObject]@{ComputerName = $Last.Trim()
                              Results = $line}
        }
    }
}
"------------"
$CsvNew 
$CsvNew | Export-Csv $FileOut -NoTypeInformation
```

Will have this output:

```
> Q:\Test\2017\08\24\SO_45870618.ps1

ComputerName Results
------------ -------
computerA     KB00000 is not installed ...
ComputerB    %windir%\somefile.exe is Version 1.2
------------
computerA    c:\SomeTestFile Version is 2
computerA    c:\SomeTestFile Version is 11.0
ComputerB    %windir%\somefile.exe is Version 1.2
```

Resulting FileOut.csv:

```
> gc .\FileOut.Csv
"ComputerName","Results"
"computerA","c:\SomeTestFile Version is 2"
"computerA","c:\SomeTestFile Version is 11.0"
"ComputerB","%windir%\somefile.exe is Version 1.2"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I did not get the same output.  It did not remove the Carriage Return in the the Results of ComputerA.


    gc c:\temp\FileOut.csv
    "ComputerName","Results"
    "computerA "," KB00000 is not installed
        c:\SomeTestFile Version is 2
        c:\SomeTestFile Version is 11.0"
    "ComputerB ","%windir%\somefile.exe is Version 1.2"

Comment: You **did** notice my `Provided your csv looks like`? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45870618/edit) your question to contain your real csv. Don't put it in a comment.

Comment: Updated CSV in question and directly posted from notepad.  Thank you

Comment: Adapted script to csv and added a Trim to strip trailing spaces from ComputerName.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!

Comment: May I ask why you unchecked my answer? Is something wrong / not working?

Comment: Follow up question.... I need to modify this to filter several items  in the results column such as "KB is, Version is, found, etc.  Is there a better way to filter/delete multiple items?

Comment: The core is the Regular Expression `$line -NotMatch '^\s*KB\d+\s+is'` It could be expanded to `or`-match other lines but that needs more example lines, best in a new question.